# import comma delimited file to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am downloading and importing a remote text file to a local mysql database.

The format has recently changed to have a comma inside one of the columns and is causing the import to fail with error "Invalid field count in CSV input on line 1."  The data now looks like:

```
"bonita","FL","212025920","2012929","Hooker,Bill"
```

How do I update this code snippet to allow for a comma within quotes?

```
foreach(explode($lineseparator,$csvcontent) as $line) {

    $lines++;

    $line = trim($line," \t");

    $line = str_replace("\r","",$line);

    /************************************
    This line escapes the special character. remove it if entries are already escaped in the csv file
    ************************************/
    $line = str_replace("'","\'",$line);
    /*************************************/

    $linearray = explode($fieldseparator,$line);

    $linemysql = implode("','",$linearray);

    $linemysql = str_replace("\"","",$linemysql);###code added

        $query = "insert ignore into $databasetable values('$linemysql');";
```

Comment: If you used the existing fgetcsv() function in PHP (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) rather than trying to write your own, then life would be a whole lot easier for you

Comment: Do you have a sample code snippet?  I am not familiar with fgetcsv at all.

Comment: The PHP manual page that I've linked shows examples

Comment: @mark that plus one on comment is coz its a good 'answer'. ANSWER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your function to :

```
     foreach(explode($lineseparator,$csvcontent) as $line) {

        $lines++;
        $line = trim($line," \t");
        $line = str_replace("\r","",$line);

        $lineArray = str_getcsv($line, ",", '"');
        $linemysql = implode("','",$lineArray);
         $query = "insert ignore into $databasetable values('$linemysql');";
        //.. Handle  the rest

     }
```

The php getcsv functions takes care of the delimiters and tracks the enclosures - saves you those headaches.

The following snippet:

```
   $line = '"bonita","FL","212025920","2012929","Hooker,Bill"';
   $array = str_getcsv($line, ",", '"');
   print_r($array);
```

outputs:

```
   Array ( [0] => bonita [1] => FL [2] => 212025920 [3] => 2012929 [4] => Hooker,Bill )
```

Comment: I replaced with this but am getting 500 server error?  

foreach(explode($lineseparator,$csvcontent) as $line) {

        $lines++;
        $line = trim($line," \t");
        $line = str_replace("\r","",$line);

        $array = str_getcsv($line, ",", '"');

 $linearray = explode($fieldseparator,$line);
 
 $linemysql = implode("','",$linearray);
 
 $linemysql = str_replace("\"","",$linemysql);###code added
 
  $query = "insert ignore into $databasetable values('$linemysql');";

     }

Comment: You don't need the line - $linearray = explode($fieldseparator,$line); again. Remove that. You have the lineArray in the str_getcsv line.

Answer (score 3):

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` with `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'` options should read the file directly. `LOAD DATA INFILE` is also faster than standard `INSERT` statements.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

This is close, but I don't think TRIM() is removing tabs:

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/my/local/file/path.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (@a, @b, @c, @d, @e) SET col1=TRIM(@a), col2=TRIM(@b), col3=TRIM(@c), col4=TRIM(@d) col5=TRIM(@e)`

Comment: so replace the $query insert with LOAD Data?  Can you provide the exact syntax so i can try it out?

Answer (score 0):

**sample table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `id` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `a1` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `b1` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `c1` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `d1` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoD1B;
```

**import query:**

```
load data local infile 'd:/import.csv' into table table1 fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
(id, a1, b1, c1, d1)
```

**import.csv**

```
"bonita1","FL1","212025920","2012929","Hooker,Bill"
"bonita2","FL2","212025920","2012929","Hooker,Bill"
"bonita3","FL3","212025920","2012929","Hooker,Bill"
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n' in the existing insert?